# Integrating 3D audio in xaudio2

Tags: c++, msdn, xaudio2

I was following the tutorial on msdn for xaudio2. 2D audio is working fine, but when I tried integrating 3D audio, it just wasnt working.

```
#include <xaudio2.h>
#include <x3daudio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment(lib,"xaudio2.lib") 

#ifdef _XBOX //Big-Endian
#define fourccRIFF 'RIFF'
#define fourccDATA 'data'
#define fourccFMT 'fmt '
#define fourccWAVE 'WAVE'
#define fourccXWMA 'XWMA'
#define fourccDPDS 'dpds'
#endif

#ifndef _XBOX //Little-Endian
#define fourccRIFF 'FFIR'
#define fourccDATA 'atad'
#define fourccFMT ' tmf'
#define fourccWAVE 'EVAW'
#define fourccXWMA 'AMWX'
#define fourccDPDS 'sdpd'
#endif

HRESULT FindChunk(HANDLE hFile, DWORD fourcc, DWORD& dwChunkSize, DWORD& dwChunkDataPosition)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

    DWORD dwChunkType;
    DWORD dwChunkDataSize;
    DWORD dwRIFFDataSize = 0;
    DWORD dwFileType;
    DWORD bytesRead = 0;
    DWORD dwOffset = 0;

    while (hr == S_OK)
    {
        DWORD dwRead;
        if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, &dwChunkType, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, NULL))
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

        if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, &dwChunkDataSize, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, NULL))
            hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());

        switch (dwChunkType)
        {
        case fourccRIFF:
            dwRIFFDataSize = dwChunkDataSize;
            dwChunkDataSize = 4;
            if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, &dwFileType, sizeof(DWORD), &dwRead, NULL))
                hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
            break;

        default:
            if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, dwChunkDataSize, NULL, FILE_CURRENT))
                return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
        }

        dwOffset += sizeof(DWORD) * 2;

        if (dwChunkType == fourcc)
        {
            dwChunkSize = dwChunkDataSize;
            dwChunkDataPosition = dwOffset;
            return S_OK;
        }

        dwOffset += dwChunkDataSize;

        if (bytesRead >= dwRIFFDataSize) return S_FALSE;

    }

    return S_OK;

}

HRESULT ReadChunkData(HANDLE hFile, void* buffer, DWORD buffersize, DWORD bufferoffset)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    if (INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER == SetFilePointer(hFile, bufferoffset, NULL, FILE_BEGIN))
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    DWORD dwRead;
    if (0 == ReadFile(hFile, buffer, buffersize, &dwRead, NULL))
        hr = HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(GetLastError());
    return hr;
}

int main()
{
    IXAudio2* pXAudio2;
    IXAudio2MasteringVoice* pMasterVoice;
    IXAudio2SourceVoice* pSource;
    X3DAUDIO_HANDLE X3DInstance;
    WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE wfx = { 0 };
    XAUDIO2_BUFFER buffer = { 0 };

    HRESULT hr;

    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr = CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT_MULTITHREADED)));

    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr = XAudio2Create(&pXAudio2, XAUDIO2_DEBUG_ENGINE, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR)));

    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr = pXAudio2->CreateMasteringVoice(&pMasterVoice)));

    //XAUDIO2_DEBUG_CONFIGURATION debug;
    //pXAudio2->SetDebugConfiguration(&debug);

    DWORD dwChannelMask;
    pMasterVoice->GetChannelMask(&dwChannelMask);

    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr = X3DAudioInitialize(dwChannelMask, X3DAUDIO_SPEED_OF_SOUND, X3DInstance)));

    X3DAUDIO_LISTENER Listener = {};
    X3DAUDIO_EMITTER Emitter = {};
    Emitter.ChannelCount = 1;
    Emitter.CurveDistanceScaler = FLT_MIN;

    XAUDIO2_VOICE_DETAILS details;
    pMasterVoice->GetVoiceDetails(&details);

    X3DAUDIO_DSP_SETTINGS DSPSettings = { 0 };
    FLOAT32* matrix = new FLOAT32[details.InputChannels];
    DSPSettings.SrcChannelCount = 1;
    DSPSettings.DstChannelCount = details.InputChannels;
    DSPSettings.pMatrixCoefficients = matrix;


    Emitter.OrientFront = { -1, 0, 0 };
    Emitter.OrientTop = { 0, 1, 0 };
    Emitter.Position = { 5, 2, 3 };
    Emitter.Velocity = { 0, 0, 0 };
    Listener.OrientFront = { 1, 0, 0 };
    Listener.OrientTop = { 0, 1, 0 };
    Listener.Position = { 0, 0, 0 };
    Listener.Velocity = { 0, 0, 0 };

    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
        (LPCSTR)"woodBreak.wav",
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        0,
        NULL);


    SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    DWORD dwChunkSize;
    DWORD dwChunkPosition;
    //check the file type, should be fourccWAVE or 'XWMA'
    FindChunk(hFile, fourccRIFF, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
    DWORD filetype;
    ReadChunkData(hFile, &filetype, sizeof(DWORD), dwChunkPosition);

    FindChunk(hFile, fourccFMT, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
    ReadChunkData(hFile, &wfx, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);

    //fill out the audio data buffer with the contents of the fourccDATA chunk
    FindChunk(hFile, fourccDATA, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);
    BYTE* pDataBuffer = new BYTE[dwChunkSize];
    ReadChunkData(hFile, pDataBuffer, dwChunkSize, dwChunkPosition);

    buffer.AudioBytes = dwChunkSize;
    buffer.pAudioData = pDataBuffer;
    buffer.Flags = XAUDIO2_END_OF_STREAM;
    buffer.LoopCount = XAUDIO2_LOOP_INFINITE;

    
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr = pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice(&pSource, (WAVEFORMATEX*)&wfx)));
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr = pSource->SubmitSourceBuffer(&buffer)));

    X3DAudioCalculate(X3DInstance, &Listener, &Emitter,
        X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_MATRIX | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_DOPPLER | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_LPF_DIRECT | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_REVERB,
        &DSPSettings);

    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr = pSource->SetFrequencyRatio(DSPSettings.DopplerFactor)));
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr = pSource->SetOutputMatrix(pMasterVoice, 1, details.InputChannels, DSPSettings.pMatrixCoefficients)));

    pSource->Start();

    int i;
    std::cin >> i;

    return 0;
}
```

The problem lies when I try to apply the 3d audio, but when I run the code the assert triggers with code 88960001 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/xaudio2-error-codes

If anybody has any idea please let me know.
I thank you in advance.

Comment: It appears you are using XAudio 2.8 (Windows 8.x) or XAudio 2.9 (Windows 10 & XAudio2Redist). You should mention which OS you are using to help diagnose problems.

Comment: Im using windows 10 with 2.9 version

Comment: BTW, don't use assert to check for failure. Consider something like [ThrowIfFailed](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ThrowIfFailed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you may want to enable debugging for XAudio2 to help you track down problems. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/xaudio2-debugging-facilities).

The HRESULT you are getting (88960001) is `XAUDIO2_E_INVALID_CALL`.

There are two problems with your code (besides the abuse of `assert` mentioned in the comments):

1. Your HRESULT failure is likely because your code only works with single-channel / mono wav files.
2. Even if you fix this, you still hear silence because you have set `Emitter.CurveDistanceScaler` to a silly value. Set it to 1 to start out.

> For the latest XAudio2 samples for Win32 desktop, see [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/master/XAudio2). There are additional samples for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/UWPSamples/Audio).

> You may also want to look at the *DirectX Tool Kit for Audio* in the *DirectX Tool Kit* [DX11](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK) / [DX12](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12).

Comment: Hello, I have edited the code so it can be copy pasted in main file and under project properties multibyte character should be used instead of unicode. If you comment the SetOutputMatrix and add a wav file to project it should play normal 2d audio. If you could please take the time to try.

Comment: What audio format is 'woodbreak.wav'? In your code you are assuming it's a mono (1-channel) sound.